# numpy: padding array with zeros

Tags: numpy, image-processing

I am working with images and I want to pad numpy array with zeros.
I looked at [np.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html/%22np.pad%22)

For padding single array it works fine

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
y = np.pad(x,(1,1), 'constant')

x
=> array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
y
=> array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

How to implement if we have `x type` arrays in a list/array , like

```
c_x=np.array([[[2,2],[2,3]],[[3,2],[2,3]],[[4,4],[2,3]]])
c_y=np.pad(c_x,((0,0),(1,1),(0,0)),'constant')  #padding is present only on top and bottom
```

As such arrays contains R,G,B channel, Can that too be accounted when padding?

**edit:**

Say `c_x` stores list of 10 images on 28x28 pixels with RGB channel

Now I want to pad all 10 images , So after modifying 10 images are of 30x30 with pixels on border as `[0,0,0]`

Comment: It it not clear to me what the desired output is.  Do you mean you want to add a border of zeros to an RGB image that is stored in an array with shape (3, m, n)?  I think you are saying that `c_y` is *not* what you want.  Could you show what the desired result is?  Just enter it by hand for the small example.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser you answered my question, I tried to put some info regarding RGB part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear to me what your desired output is, but I think it is either `np.pad(c_x, ((1,1), (0,0), (0,0)), mode='constant')` or `np.pad(c_x, ((0,0), (1,1), (1,1)), mode='constant')`:

```
In [228]: c_x
Out[228]: 
array([[[2, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[3, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [2, 3]]])

In [229]: np.pad(c_x, ((1,1), (0,0), (0,0)), mode='constant')
Out[229]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[3, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [2, 3]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0]]])

In [230]: np.pad(c_x, ((0,0), (1,1), (1,1)), mode='constant')
Out[230]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 4, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: Yup, seems like OP loves the `np.pad` and would go with it :)

Comment: @Warren Weckesser: It is very useful. If I consider the image RGB. I want to add the zero padding the image so that my original image is in center of the new image (i.e 256x256x3-->512x512x3). So is my code correct?   `delta_w = width_new - image.shape[0]
    delta_h = height_new - image.shape[1]
    top, bottom = delta_h // 2, delta_h - (delta_h // 2)
    left, right = delta_w // 2, delta_w - (delta_w // 2)
    image= np.pad(image, ((top, bottom), (left, right), (0,0)), mode='constant')`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using initialization of output array with `zeros` and then assigning values into it -

```
def pad3D(c_x, padlen=1):
    m,n,r = c_x.shape
    c_y = np.zeros((m, n+2*padlen, r+2*padlen),dtype=c_x.dtype)
    c_y[:, padlen:-padlen, padlen:-padlen] = c_x
    return c_y
```

Now, considering that arrays could be image data and usually you might have the channel being represented by the last axis, while the first two axes representing the height and width, we need to change the indexing there. The modified portions would be the initialization and assignment :

```
c_y = np.zeros((m+2*padlen, n+2*padlen, r),dtype=c_x.dtype)
c_y[padlen:-padlen, padlen:-padlen, :] = c_x
```

So, if you notice, we are slicing with `padlen:-padlen` along the axes that needs padding. Using this general theory, you can handle various image data arrays for padding.

Sample run -

```
In [422]: c_x
Out[422]: 
array([[[2, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[3, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [2, 3]]])

In [423]: pad3D(c_x, padlen=1) # pads all across not just top and bottom
Out[423]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 4, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: your implementation is good, but is it possible to do with `np.pad` itself without indexing and slicing

Answer (score 1):

try this. with use of `np.pad` 
I know I m late but, It might help someone. :)

```
def padwithzero(vector, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    vector[:pad_width[0]] = 0
    vector[-pad_width[1]:] = 0
    return vector


tmp_mainImg = np.pad(mainImg, 1, padwithzero)

print(tmp_mainImg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated @Divakar's answer for 2D matrices:

```
import numpy
def pad2D(c_x, padlen=1):
    m, n = c_x.shape
    c_y = np.zeros((m + 2 * padlen, n + 2 * padlen), dtype = c_x.dtype)
    c_y[padlen:-padlen, padlen:-padlen] = c_x
    return c_y
```

this should also work with [Numba!](https://numba.pydata.org/)

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython = True)
def pad2D(c_x, padlen=1):
    m, n = c_x.shape
    c_y = np.zeros((m + 2 * padlen, n + 2 * padlen), dtype = c_x.dtype)
    c_y[padlen:-padlen, padlen:-padlen] = c_x
    return c_y
```